# remove keyManager bean in securityContext file?

Tags: spring, spring-saml, jks, saml-2.0

How can I remove the keyManager bean in securityContext.xml and the jks file ?
I don't really need it to generate the metadata of my Service Provider.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See [Spring SAML manual chapter 8.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/security.html):

> In case your application doesn't need to create digital signatures
>   and/or decrypt incoming messages, it is possible to use an empty
>   implementation of the keystore which doesn't require any JKS file -
>   org.springframework.security.saml.key.EmptyKeyManager.